# i want to import this postgreSQL output to file

Tags: postgresql, psql

the following code is correct ?
i want to store foo table output to file.txt file how to write shell script for this

```
psql <<EOF
   \pset format wrapped
    SELECT * FROM foo;
EOF |tee -a file.txt
```

Comment: $PSQL -d $DB -U $USER -p $PORT <<EOF
\pset format wrapped 

select datname, pid,now() - query_start as "runtime",state,state_change,query from pg_stat_activity WHERE  pid <> pg_backend_pid() 
AND state in ('idle') 
AND state_change < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;
EOF |tee -a /tmp/KILL_ALL_IDLE.log   i want this output in correct format  that is why i used pset format but it will throwing error

Comment: when i using this format it output showing lenthy IDLECONN=`$PSQL -d $DB -U $USER -p $PORT -t -c "select count(*) from pg_stat_activity where state='idle' ;"`
echo "Count of IDLE connections  more than 15min: $IDLECONN" |tee -a  $DETAIL

Comment: Sorry, this is garbage. Try to format the question and put your comments above into it.